# Run two C programs simultaneously sharing memory, how?

Tags: c, memory, shared

I have two c files: producer.c and consumer.c. Consumer creates a shared buffer in memory and waits producer to put items into buffer to consume. Producer attaches shared memory to its memory map, then starts putting items into buffer.

The question is how to compile and run them together?

Here is the actual assignment. (I know I can do it with one c file using threads, but this is not I am asked to do.)

> In this part you will develop a producer-consumer application that
>   will use shared  memory for process communication (POSIX shared
>   memory, not System V shared  memory). There will be N producers and N
>   consumers. N can be 1, 2, or 3.
>
> You will develop a producer program (producer.c) and a consumer
>   program  (consumer.c). When started, the producer program will create
>   N child processes which  will be acting as N producers (i.e. each
>   child process will be a producer process).
>
> Similarly, when started, the consumer program will create N child
>   processes, where  each child process will be acting as a consumer
>   process. You will consider that  consumers are identified as 0, 1, 2,
>   depending on N. For example, if N is 2, then there  will two
>   consumers, 0 and 1.
>
> The consumer program will be run first. When run, the consumer program
>   will first create  a shared memory of size  4 KB. This shared memory
>   will be the place where you will  have a shared single buffer sitting.
>   The buffer can be accessed by producers and  consumers. The buffer
>   size is 100. It can hold at most 100 items (integers). In the shared 
>   memory you can have some other shared variables that you feel
>   necessary. The  consumer program will also create one or  more
>   semaphores (you decide how many).
>
> Then it will create N child processes (N consumers) using the fork()
>   system call (You will  not need to use the exec() system call). The
>   main process of the consumer program  (parent), after creating the
>   child processes, should not terminate. It should wait until all 
>   children (i.e. consumers) finish their tasks and terminate. When all
>   children terminate, it  will remove (delete) the shared memory from
>   the system. It will also remove (delete) the  semaphores.  Then it can
>   terminate as well.
>
> Each producer will read an input file of positive integers (one
>   integer per line) and will  just pass the integers through a shared
>   buffer sitting in a shared memory (created by the  consumer program)
>   between the producers and consumers.
>
> Each consumer will read integers from the shared buffer and will write
>   a received integer  z to an output file associated with consumer if  z
>   mod N is equal to the ID of the  consumer.  For example, if N is 3 and
>   if the ID of a consumer is 2 and the consumer has   received an
>   integer 7, it will do nothing with it (ignore), but if it receives 8,
>   it will write the integer to its output file. An output file will
>   contain one integer in a line.    While producers and consumers are
>   accessing the shared buffer, they should use  semaphores so that
>   access is synchronized. Additionally, if the buffer is full, producers
>   should sleep, and if there is nothing to consume, consumers should
>   sleep. We should  not have busy waiting. You will use POSIX semaphores
>   (named semaphores). The consumer program will be invoked as follows:
>   consumer  N  …
>
> Here, N is the number of consumer processes to be created.  The value
>   of this  parameter must be the same with the corresponding parameter
>   of the producer program.    Here, the  is the name of the
>   output file that will be used by the consumer with  ID X.  The number
>   of output file names entered will be equal to N.  is a name  we
>   can use to identify the shared memory.  is a name we can use to
>   identify  the semaphores (it can be a prefix that can be used for
>   names of many semaphores).  These same names must be used when
>   invoking the producer.   The producer program will be named as
>   producer and will be invoked with the following  parameters:
>   producer N   …
>
> Here, N is the number of producers. The  is the name of an
>   input file for  producer X. An input file is a text file storing
>   integers.  The number of input file names we enter will be equal to N.
>   There can be one or more integers in a file. An input file can be
>   quite huge (billions of integers).  is a name we can use to
>   identify the shared  memory.  is a name we can use to identify
>   the semaphores.
>
> An example invocation of the programs can be like the following.
>   consumer 3 out0.txt out1.txt out2.txt mysmem mysemaphores  producer 3
>   in0.txt in1.txt in2.txt mysmem mysemaphore

Comment: What do you mean by "together" exactly?

Comment: You'll need one of these new-fashioned multi-tasking operating systems. Unix systems got that thing on mainframes for a while, and I've heard you can get it at home on this fancy new Amiga computer.

Comment: My OS is MacOSX Lion. There is nothing to do with OS, since these OS can do multi-tasking etc.

Comment: parallel programming? maybe threads?

Comment: asking for shared memory has nothing to do with OS? you're kidding no? It looks that you are new to SO, but questions here need to be posed precisely, telling us what you have and what you want to achieve. We are not here to do your "homework". Did you google for "producer consumer shared memory"?

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question a little. If you are able to compile two different binaries, and your question is about synchronization, then please precise it in your question. This allows people with the same problem as yours to find this question via a search engine.

Comment: I know what I am doing and asking. I already implemented the assignment with threads in a single file. Now I am trying to implement it with two different c files.

Answer (score 5):

The question is how to **synchronize two processes sharing some memory**. You could use [Posix semaphores](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview), but there are many other ways to do that.

Comment: I already implemented semaphores. The question is how can I compile and run producer.c and consumer.c. For example, consumer.c creates buffer and waits producer to put item into buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `main()` to each of your modules. Compile each separately to become two *different* binaries and run them.

Comment: Both files have own main functions. However, the problem is they work on bounded shared memory, and sometimes one needs to wait the other and the other way around.

Comment: @user853005: Basile Starynkevitch's proposal would be a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot simply share memory. You have to ask the operating system to provide you access to memory that can be shared with another process. The API to use depends on your OS. Also, even on something like Linux, there is more than one way to do this with different pros, cons and limitations. Here is another question where some of the alternatives are discussed [Shmem vs tmpfs vs mmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904581/shmem-vs-tmpfs-vs-mmap)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Semaphores,and shared memeory.In Linux environment, I suggest POSIX Semaphores used for process and System V shared memory,also other way could realize it the same ,it just because i think these methods are easy.